# Express unit sphere as countable union of great circles?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $S = \{x\in \mathbb{R^3} | d(x,(0,0,0))=1\}.$   Is it possible that $S$ is a countable union of “great circles”? A great circle is the intersection of $S$ with a plane through $(0,0,0)$.

What I know is that the sphere is closed and bounded, so it is compact, so given any open cover there is a subcover. But great circles are closed, so probably it's not gonna work out.

Then I thought of using contradiction. But each great circles are uncountable. Countably union of uncountable set is still uncountable.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the answer hinting at Baire Category:

The sphere $S^2$ is a complete metric space (use metric induced by Euclidean metric restricted to $S^2$). By Baire, a complete metric space cannot be a countable union of nowhere dense sets. But a "great circle" is nowhere dense: It is closed and its interior is empty (both easy to see).

Comment: Uhh that's a little bit different from what I've learnt about the Baire. The version I have says that if we have a sequence of open dense sets, then their union has to be dense. Was my idea in that comment wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Misakov The version I state is equivalent to yours if you replace union with intersection (see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem). In your other comment, if you replace dense with open dense in the conclusion then yes, it seems to me that you can argue like that.

Answer (score 8):

you may reduce the dimension of your question by considering the intersections of your great circles with a suitably chosen equator.

so can a circle be made up of a countable set of points?

Comment: if the great circles cover the sphere, then they certainly cover an equator, which is a subset of the sphere

Comment: @whacka: The term "covering" implies that every point on the sphere -- and so in particular every point on the chose equator -- must be on at least one of the circles.

Comment: Ah, sorry. For some reason I was thinking of an equator as one of the great circles, but the point is we need to choose an equator which is not one of the great circles.

Comment: still that is a good point. i deliberately sidestepped the problem by using the phrase "suitably chosen", Robert's method avoids these complexities

Answer (score 7):

If you have measure theory available, you can recognize that great circles have zero area and so any countable union of them will have zero area, but the sphere has positive area.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: the Baire category theorem.

Comment: each plane $P_i$ consisting great circle is closed, so $\mathbb{R}^3-P_i$ is open. also it's dense, so their intersection should be dense. but their intersection is empty, so it's impossible?

Comment: @Misakov I elaborated on this hint. Maybe it helps you answer your comment here.

Answer (score 1):

suppose first that every great circle is in the collection. then the sphere is also covered by the poles of the great circles. but there are only 2 poles per great circle, so the sphere itself has only a countable set of points. contradiction.

so there is a great circle not included in the collection. but this is now the union of its intersections with the circles of the collection, and we obtain a contradiction as before. this time because any two great circles meet in exactly  two points.